# How can I limit appended text to EditText to a single character without limiting the EditText?

Tags: android, string, button, android-edittext

I have two buttons and an edittext. Each button has their own set of text set through a StringArray.

My issue is that when I click, say, ButtonA two times to get to character #2 in the array, it pops up twice. How can I prevent this?

Pastebin of source is here: http://pastebin.com/57PsZH5D

Relevant bits:

```
    String[] keyOne = {"A", "B", "C"};
    String[] keyTwo = {"D", "E", "F"};
    String pressedKey;

    public void delayAction(View v) {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            et.getText().append(pressedKey);
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 500);

}
    // Inside onclick

    case R.id.button1:
            counter++;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            pressedKey = keyOne[counter];
            delayAction(v);
                    if (counter >= 3) {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
            break;
    case R.id.button2:
            counter++;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            pressedKey = keyTwo[counter];
            delayAction(v);
                    if (counter >= 3) {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
            break;
```

Comment: post your relevant code here, please

Comment: Assuming you are in an Activity, why do you have the `Handler` in this way?

Comment: Is there a better way? I thought it would leave less code around and only run when I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static boolean variable say `checkVal` and initialize with `false` and in click event of button A check the value of `checkVal` if it Is false then add the string and change value of `checkVal` to true now when secind time you click the button it will not add anything.

Comment: What if OP wants the third value?

Comment: Ok so you can write a code in else condition where you can compare the value of previous edittext with the currently entered if both matches then dont do anything and if they dont match then chamge the value and again append the string

Comment: You want to append in the string or you want to replace the added character with the new one

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to emulated T9 input? What you'd want to do is cancel the runnable.

handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

Actually, now that I think about it more, if you're trying to do T9 input, then don't do anything delayed.  Immediately post the character and note the time (System.currentTimeMillis() and the last key pressed.  When the next key is pressed, if it's the same key and the new time is less than some cutoff, then erase the last character and put the new one up.  Doing this will give the user immediate visual feedback on their keypresses.

Comment: Why yes. Yes I am, haha. How would I go about noting the last key pressed?

Comment: Just store that as a variable.